# Enums and case statements

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am looking for good reasons if we should try and avoid switch/case statements and how to do this for enumerations, and suggestions how, consider the following example:
(note that this switch/case may be scattered all over the code base)

```
switch (theEnum)
{
    case MyEnum.Enum1:
        // dosomething
    case MyEnum.Enum2:
        // do something
    case MyEnum.Enum3:
        // do something
    default:
       throw new Exception("Unsupported enumeration: " + theEnum.ToString());
```

}

vs.

```
public Dictionary<MyEnum, StrategyBase> BuildMapper()
{
    var mapper = new Dictionary<MyEnum, StrategyBase>();
    mapper[MyEnum.Enum1] = new Strategy1();
    mapper[MyEnum.Enum2] = new Strategy2();
    mapper[MyEnum.Enum3] = new Strategy3();
return mapper;
}

BuildMapper()[MyEnum.Enum1].DoSomething();
```

Option 2 is more OO but I was wondering what others thinks as this approach and if there are good and compelling reasons why we should strive to do this or not.

One may argue principles such as switch/else will violate open-close for instance.

Comment: if your concentrating on the Cyclometric complexity and if the methods always needs to be extensible then OO approach is better.

Comment: It should be noted that the switch will perform MUCH faster. Walking a list is also going to be faster than using a dictionary, unless you have around 10 or more items in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For OO you should use [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* the Visitor Pattern should be used instead and weather it is feasible as replacement for simple switch/case statements as for those it seems a bit overkill IMHO.

Comment: Actually i like this idea, the visitor may require extra plumbing, but where it is better over a strategy is the strategy would need a class for each enumeration and each operation where the visitor will be a class per set of operations (easier to maintain)

Comment: There is a way that you can do the double dispatch automatically by using reflection to map the enum to a method, the con of this is the dynamic nature means the compiler wont detect breaking changes to the enum, however one can possibly come up with an attribute to represent the enum on top of the method, then you will get help from the compiler

Answer (score 1):

I would make `BuildMapper` as static (as well read-only) because it will always return you the same Dictionary set.

As far as why this is good, the reason should be simple, when you have a design where things map from one thing to other and this mapping will always be static, it is obvious to represent it as dictionary rather then if/else or switch case which hides the intention that it was just a mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the switch if it's just in one or two places. If, as you say, "this switch/case may be scatterred all over the code base", then go for the second solution.

It's not only more OO, which is good, but easier to maintain in your situation. Concerns about performance and memory consumption are totally irrelevant in this case, go for ease of maintenance first and optimize if needed (but I don't think that you will ever need to optimize *this*).

Also the readability loss is irrelevant in this case - understanding what the second approach does takes very little time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first variant is better because It looks more readable and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it all comes down to what you want to achieve. Its easier to read the first sample and that is kinda important if you share your code base with others. A BuilderMapper might be useful if you are following some pattern

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are comparing oranges and apples.

The switch is a sequential comparison between a variable and several constant data. Unless you have a 1K-cases switch, it should be much more performing than the Dictionary.

Of course, the switch is much less memory consuming, than a quite complex object as the Dictionary is.

Finally, the Enums are not constrained to the declared options, but may be combined as "Flags". This feature won't be available by using the hashmap.

Is it satisfying?

Comment: The performance issue you mention is a good point, but how much performance are we talking 10 micro sec? i dont know but probably negilable for 99% of business line applications. Using the enum as a 'Flag' is also true but one can always compose the actual enum value inside the strategy class?

Comment: That's true. I have two only points about the question: (1) the switch gives you the ability to compose at no cost by "jumping" from a case to another one, and (2) the switch is an imperative approach, while the hashmap is functional.
No other clues!...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer you...the underlying type of an Enum is an integer. Thus you may use any composition of Enums, as long you won't break the type safety. BTW the Enum is NOT value-safe!